# How to set dials to values given as input in angular gauge fusion chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion chart library. In that I am using Angular Gauge chart for my report. I'm facing issue with dial which is automatically set by fusion chart library based on dial value we are passing to it.

Its splitting the min and max into 4 equal divisions and displaying. I want to overwrite it. I want to display the max value of each section given by us.

current output :

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

My code is here :

```
var bw1 = parseInt($('.ideal_weight_graph').data('ideal1'));//46
    var bw2 = parseInt($('.ideal_weight_graph').data('ideal2'));//62
    var bw = parseInt($('.ideal_weight_graph').data('weight'));//53

    var bw3 = bw2 + bw1;

    var fusioncharts = new FusionCharts({
        type : 'angulargauge',
        renderAt : 'ideal_weight_graph',
        width : '400',
        height : '250',
        dataFormat : 'json',
        dataSource : {
            "chart" : {
                "caption" : "Your weight for your gender and age",
                "lowerLimit" : 0,
                "upperLimit" : bw3,
                "lowerLimitDisplay" : "Under weight",
                "middleLimitDisplay" : "Normal weight",
                "upperLimitDisplay" : "Over weight",
                "showValue" : "1",
                "valueBelowPivot" : "1",
                "theme" : "fint",
                showGaugeBorder : "1"
            },
            "colorRange" : {
                "color" : [{
                    "minValue" : 0,
                    "maxValue" : bw1,
                    "code" : "#e44a00"
                }, {
                    "minValue" : bw1,
                    "maxValue" : bw2,
                    "code" : "#00CC00"
                }, {
                    "minValue" : bw2,
                    "maxValue" : bw3,
                    "code" : "#f8bd19"
                }]
            },
            "dials" : {
                "dial" : [{
                    "value" : bw
                }]
            }
        }
    });
    fusioncharts.render();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Shanthi You may achieve your requirement by using the 'trend points' feature of Angular Gauge of FusionCharts.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/79ty21su/) is a working sample for your requirement.

```
<!-- A simple angular gauge showing customer satisfaction index for Harry's Supermart. 

Elements :
1. Color Range (Radial scale)
2. Dials (Data Value Indicators)
3. Tick Marks & Values
4. Tooltip
5. Trend points, trend arcs & trend markers
6. Annotations

-->
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Please let me know if you have further concerns.

Comment: Is there any way to hide the default points in the Angular gauge ?

Comment: @Shanthi Yes, you can do so by providing value '0' to 'showTickValues' attribute and enable the extreme point value visible by providing '1' value to 'showLimits'. However, it seems that 'showLimits' is not working right now when 'showTickValues' has value '0'. Thank you! :)